# Get Body Items for Unread Emails from an specific Mail ID in an Outlook Account

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

Would Like to appreciate the answer for below Question

I have trying to read the latest 5 Unread emails from an Specific mail Id and fetch the Mail Body data in a variable.

I have tried using Below Code :

```
import win32com.client
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items

received_dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'Info@gmail.com'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Sample Report'")

try:
    for message in list(messages):
    try:
        s = message.sender
        for body in message.Body:
```

Answer (score 0):

The *approach* with using the `Restrict` method is correct, but you need to call it once with a combined search criteria assembled into a single search criteria string. So, instead of calling the Restrict method three times in a row:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'Info@gmail.com'")
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'Sample Report'")
```

You can use logical operators like AND and OR. For example:

```
search_criteria = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "' AND [SenderEmailAddress] = 'Info@gmail.com' AND [Subject] = 'Sample Report'"
```

The `Restrict` methods doesn't let you pick up only the required/limited number of items. You may also consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class where you could iterate over the required number of items. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you only need unread messages, you need to add an extra restriction: `[Unread] = true`. As Eugene noted, you need to combine all restrictions into a single restriction.

Also, since you don't want all matches, you might want to use `Items.Find/FindNext` instead of `Items.Restrict` - this way you can exit the loop after you find 5 matches rather than retrieving all of them from `Restrict`.